# Remove and replace a production git repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need to replace a git repository on a production site. I have been working on a mirrored git repo that has staging and production branches. Ive done the work on staging, tested it and merged it into production branch and all is good. Pushed to remote and added the remote as origin onto production server. so now I have two remotes - old_dev and origin.n I fetched the origin remote. If I run git branch it shows the two branches that are on the old_dev. I want to remove the old_dev and checkout to production on the 'origin' repo.

At this point I am unsure where i am. I am inclined to remove the old_dev remote but I am a little nervous.

I have done this:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/production

and running git branch just shows: master and production.

At this point I am unsure where i am. I am inclined to remove the old_dev remote but I am a little nervous. If I look at the live site, the code is not there so I assume I am not on the production branch pulled from the origin (new) remote.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the new remote, you can name it as you like, e.g.

```
git remote add new-production <git-url>
```

Then you would be able to see the difference. 
You can list the remotes by running

```
git remote -v
```

This will show you the remotes

You can then do 
`git pull -u new-production production`

once you feel comfortable with that code, you can remove the old remote

```
git remote rm origin
```

You should also remember to `git fetch && git checkout <new_branch>` once you have you're remote squared away